# In the app permission is also denied in the firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to coding
The database contains the following cats

url

https://"bucket_name".firebaseio.com/Users/ID/"$uid"

```
 {
  "Age" : "\"2000,0,0\"",
  "Points today" : "110",
  "Questions" : {
    "All questions" : {
     
    },
    "Default questions" : {
     
    }
  },
  "Ready to challenge" : "\"yes\"",
  "Spirit" : "5",
  "account status" : "\"active\"",
  "country" : "\"AE\"",
  "email" : "\"email\"",
  "language" : "\"ar\"",
  "name" : "\"name\"",
  "password " : "\"siwasiwa\"",
  "phone number" : "\"\"",
  "points" : "120",
  "profile picture" : "\"55\"",
  "timezone" : "\"123"",
  "user name" : "\"\""
```

I activated google authentication in the project as follows firebase rules look

```
 { 
  "rules": {
    "bucket_name":{
      "Users":{
        "ID" :{
          "$uid": {
            "Age": {
              ".read": true,
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
              "Points today": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "Questions": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
              "Spirit": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
              "Ready to challenge": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null"
            },
              "account status": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
              "country": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
              "email": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "language": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "name": {
              ".read": true,
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "password": {
              ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "phone number": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "points": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "profile picture": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "timezone": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
               "user name": {
              ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            }
          }
            
       
             
             
             
             
             
         }
      
      },
    }
    }
  }
```

The result every time I do the simulation read and write is rejected
Also, he tried more than one way, but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use Realtime database security rules to protect a storage bucket.  That's not possible.  Cloud Storage has a completely different set of rules to use.  These are described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).